# generate DO from JAXB objects

Tags: java, jaxb, domain-object

Is there any way to generate Java Domain Objects from JAXB generated objects?

I have the following file and need to generate Domain Object from it.

Actually I removed some lines from this code and need to add some water to my text for postring my question there

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for author complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="author">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="firstName" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="lastName" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "author", propOrder = {
"firstName",
"lastName"
})
public class Author {
    protected String firstName;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the firstName property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the firstName property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setFirstName(String value) {
        this.firstName = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show an example of a domain object.